# React Hooks: useEffect with dependecy also called when component mounts

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

In React, you can use *useEffect()* hook with a dependency on it.

```
const [data, setData] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(data.test.test);
}, [data]);
```

So I would assume that this *useEffect* is just called when the data is changed.
So let´s assume I would make an api call and use *setData(response.data)*.

Then the *useEffect()* should be triggerd, since the *data* state is a dependecy.

Then the *console.log(data.tes.test)* would be working, since I got the right data.
However, I get an *undefined* error, which comes from the fact that useEffect() is also called initially.

How can I avoid this? This is pretty annoying and in my mind not a good design with regard to adding a dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two solutions. As @Woohaik has already mentioned, checking for data existence in the useEffect. I'd implement a guard:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!data) return
  console.log(data.test.test)
}, [data])
```

or you could make yourself acquainted with optional chaining (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(data?.test?.test)
}, [data])
```